Excel formular with indirect to select column in tabular fails with wrong code message
I want to sum over a tabular with a search value in a selected column
Without Indirect it looks like this
=SUMMEWENN(Data[Verwendungszweck];"*"& [@Stichwort] & "*";Data[Betrag])

The value for the search is in column Suche, here thus with content "Verwendungszweck"
If I try this with indirect I get:
=SUMMEWENN(INDIREKT("Data["&[@[Suche] &"]");"*"& [@Stichwort] & "*";Data[Betrag])

However this is not excepted by excel. What is wrong?

you have an extra [: INDIREKT("Data["&[@Suche] &"]")

correct, was more simple than I thought.
